# How to wrap entire section list in a TouchableOpacity component in react native

Tags: react-native

I currently have a section list in one of my components.  This is the code:

```
<SectionList
  renderItem={({item, index, section}) =>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.onPressOrder(item) }>
    <View>
      <Text key={index}>
      {item}
      </Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
}
  renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
  )}
  sections={this.state.dataSource}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
/>
```

the data is being pulled from `this.state.dataSource`

```
dataSource.push({
  data: [
    listItem.inspector,
    listItem.inspection_date,
    listItem.inspection_time_display,
    listItem.id
],
  key: keyId,
  title: listItem.address
  })
```

That's how I create my data source. Once it renders it displays like so:
[image]

The way the list renders each one of the elements on it's own line has it's own separate TouchableOpacity.  What I want is for the whole block of the data to be it's own opacity.  Is this possible with the SectionList data to be wrapped in a TouchableOpacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to wrap each section of the section list, but it seems like you could just as easily render the entire `listItem` as a single item, so each section has only a single element in `data`.

```
<SectionList
  renderItem={({item, index, section}) =>
  // render the entire item in the `renderItem` call with one `TouchableOpacity`
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.onPressOrder(item.id) }>
    <View>
      <Text>
      {item.inspector}
      </Text>
    </View>
     <View>
      <Text>
      {item.inspection_date}
      </Text>
    </View>
    ... etc.
  </TouchableOpacity>
}
  renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
  )}
  sections={this.state.dataSource}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>

dataSource.push({
  // each section just has one list item that is the full list item
  data: [
    listItem,
  ],
  key: keyId,
  title: listItem.address
  })
```